# How to hide params of url in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, url, sinatra

I hava a Sinatra web app.

the url like this:

> http://test.com:9393/signup?   username=&email=liubei@test.com&nickname=&gender=&birthday=&password=123456&password_confirmation=123456

How to remove params in url.Make the url in browser is:
http://test.com:9393/signup

and also can get params

Answer (score 7):

You cannot just *hide* them.

What you need here is to use `POST` request rather then `GET` one. 
`GET` requests always send their parameters in query string.

Comment: but, in rails, there isn't that condition.I post a request, there are some errors,so the url chang to that.

Comment: Could you please provide more information?

There is nothing about sinatra, rails and even ruby here: it's about HTTP protocol. As comes from your question, you use GET request to signup method, it's wrong: you shoulf use POST request instead.

Comment: @MarioDu Roman is right, see http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post. If you weren't getting this problem in Rails it's because something was set up differently that made the request a POST, it's nothing to do with the frameworks. If you're getting this happen from a form, make sure the `method` attribute is set to "POST".

Comment: this is a signup action,the method is post, but something wrong in the form data,so signup failed, the first url is the original form page, and has a flash, tell user errors,it's a get method.As I known, in Rails, the url doesn't like this, how it deal?

Comment: @roman.brodetski ,@iain, for example, Redmine, a project manage app.In sign in page,if you input wrong password or username, it will tell you errors,but url doesn't change, it use ajax?

Comment: or restful? how sinatra do it?

Comment: No, it doesn't use AJAX: it POSTs to /signup, validation fails, and then POST action renders the form with user's original input and, probably, validation errors. So the url doesn't change.

Comment: Yes, it is.
Take a look here: http://www.tenslashsix.com/blog/2011/12/01/prototyping-restful-services-with-sinatra/